# Is it right to say "as certain as can be"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can we say that somebody is as certain as can be without referring to a subject?

If so, what could this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but a subject must have been established or it won't have any meaning.
"Are you sure there aren't any UFOs?"
"I'm as certain as can be."

"Is he sure the stock market will fall?"
"He's as certain as can be."

Comment: thank you it's clear to me now